# Access values within S3 list-like objects with mutate() (or extract values from within S3 objects)

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to be able to apply operations to a data frame (tibble) column that contains S3 list-like objects, to act on one of the named items from each object in the column. As per the bottom of the question, I have this working using `sapply()` within `mutate()`, but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

Where information is stored in columns containing atomic data, dplyr functions like `mutate()` work as expected. This works, for example:

```
library(dplyr)
people_cols <- tibble(name = c("Fiona Foo", "Barry Bar", "Basil Baz"),
                  height_mm = c(1750, 1700, 1800),
                  weight_kg = c(75, 73, 74)) %>%
  mutate(height_inch = height_mm / 25.4)
people_cols
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   name          height_mm   weight_kg   height_inch
#   <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 Fiona Foo     1750        75          68.89764
# 2 Barry Bar     1700        73          66.92913
# 3 Basil Baz     1800        74          70.86614
```

But I want to work with data in S3 list objects. Here is a toy example:

```
person_stats <- function(name, height_mm, weight_kg) {
  this_person <- structure(list(name = name,
                                height_mm = height_mm,
                                weight_kg = weight_kg),
                           class = "person_stats")
}

fiona <- person_stats("Fiona Foo", 1750, 75)
barry <- person_stats("Barry Bar", 1700, 73)
basil <- person_stats("Basil Baz", 1800, 74)

fiona$height_mm
# [1] 1750
```

I can put these objects into a tibble column like this:

```
people <- tibble(personstat = list(fiona, barry, basil))

people
# # A tibble: 3 × 1
# personstat
#     <list>
#   1 <S3: person_stats>
#   2 <S3: person_stats>
#   3 <S3: person_stats>
```

But if I try to use mutate() on the column containing those objects I get errors:

```
people <- tibble(personstat = list(fiona, barry, basil)) %>%
  mutate(height_inch = personstat$height_mm / 25.4)
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'personstat' not found
```

Trying to keep it as simple as possible - if I can even reference the named items on their own then I could at least get them into a new column, and then from that do whatever operations on them:

```
people <- tibble(personstat = list(fiona, barry, basil)) %>%
  mutate(height_mm = personstat$height_mm)
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#  Unsupported type NILSXP for column "height_mm"
```

Note the different error, which is interesting - it's no longer complaining about finding the column, just struggling with the named item.

I can get it to work using base functions, `cbind()` and `sapply()` with `[[` as the function:

```
people <- tibble(personstat = list(fiona, barry, basil)) %>%
  cbind(height_mm = sapply(.$personstat, '[[', name="height_mm"))

people
#            personstat height_mm
# 1 Fiona Foo, 1750, 75      1750
# 2 Barry Bar, 1700, 73      1700
# 3 Basil Baz, 1800, 74      1800
```

Though that loses the tibble-iness.

```
class(people)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

And finally, that got me to this, which works, but it feels like using `sapply()` sort of misses the point of dplyr `mutate()`, which I think should work all the way down a column without needing that:

```
people <- tibble(personstat = list(fiona, barry, basil)) %>%
   mutate(height_mm = sapply(.$personstat, '[[', name="height_mm"))
people
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#           personstat height_mm
#               <list>     <dbl>
# 1 <S3: person_stats>      1750
# 2 <S3: person_stats>      1700
# 3 <S3: person_stats>      1800
```

Is there any way of using `mutate()` to get the output as above, without having to rely on something like `sapply()`? Or, indeed, any other sensible ways of extracting named values from within list-like S3 objects stored in a column of a tibble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rowwise` can handle such case:

```
people <- tibble(personstat = list(fiona, barry, basil))

people %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(height_mm = personstat$height_mm)
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#           personstat height_mm
# <list>     <dbl>
# 1 <S3: person_stats>      1750
# 2 <S3: person_stats>      1700
# 3 <S3: person_stats>      1800

people %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(height_inch = personstat$height_mm / 25.4)

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#           personstat height_inch
# <list>       <dbl>
# 1 <S3: person_stats>    68.89764
# 2 <S3: person_stats>    66.92913
# 3 <S3: person_stats>    70.86614
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wan't aware of `rowwise()`, but it looks like just the job. However, I'm getting some errors doing what you suggest. The top version works, but the version with the `height_inch =` calculation throws an error. I am using dplyr v0.5.0 (latest on CRAN). Unfortunately the GitHub version is not installing for me at the moment. Perhaps you are using a newer / development version?

Comment: The error message is `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'personstat' not found`.

Comment: @jamse, I use dplyr 0.6.0 pre-release (available from github) in the above code. I see the same error with v0.5.0. It might be a bug for v0.5.0. I am not sure.

Comment: Closing the loop on this one: with the newly released version (the v0.6.0 became v0.7.0 when it headed to CRAN, I think) this now works a treat. Many thanks!

Comment: This solution no longer works in dplyr 1.0.0

Comment: @stoneg64 what did you mean by "no longer works"? I tested with dplyr 1.0.7 and it stills works (the exact code in this answer still produced the expected result ). The only problem is that rstudio could not display such tibble correctly on my device.

Comment: @mt1022 In trying to mutate a dataframe to add a new column of s3 objects I receive the error "vec_ptype2.integer.integer() is implemented at C level".  The call is similar to this - return_df <- data_frame %>% rowwise()  %>% mutate ( new_column=filter_for_lapply_of_df(S3_Table, level)).  The column S3_table contains an S3Object.  The new column will also contain S3Objects of the same type.  The command works as expected in 0.8.6.  This issue seems related to https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/issues/1380

Comment: @stoneg64 I am not sure what's going wrong. I suggest posting a new question so that someone more familiar with this could help.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep it in the `tidyverse` you could use `purrr::map_dbl` here:

```
library(tidyverse)    
people %>% mutate(height = map_dbl(personstat, "height_mm"))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've accepted the other answer as it's just dplyr and a little clearer to my eye, but this does work too. For those wanting to use a `map_dbl` version, if you want to do a calculation as well as extracting the variable you can include it outside of the map_dbl call like so: `people %>% mutate(height_inch = map_dbl(personstat, "height_mm") / 25.4)`